# Implementation of Android EventSource Using Git REPO https://github.com/streamdataio/eventsource-android/ private onConnect Error

Tags: android, git, github, private, eventsource

I am using a EventSource REPO by  https://github.com/streamdataio/eventsource-android/ 
and I created an onConnect (); method, however, the eventsource.connect();method is underlined red and says that I cannot access it because it is private? I looked online and everyone uses this REPO with no problem what going on here?

```
 private void connect() {
    // Create headers: Add the streamdata.io app token
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("X-Sd-Token", streamdataioAppToken);

    // Create the EventSource with API URL & Streamdata.io authentication token
    try {
        eventSource = new EventSource(new URI(streamdataioProxyPrefix), new URI(myApiUrl), new SSEHandler(), headers);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Start data receiving
    eventSource.connect();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm Lorie, from streamdata.io. Thanks for looking a our sample projet. Indeed, you are the first user reporting such an issue. Nothing seems wrong with the piece of code you provided. Please make sure that your eventSource object is declared earlier in your code with EventSource type, and that you import the right EventSource class : tylerjroach.com.eventsource_android.EventSource;
If you still encounter the issue, I'd suggest you drop your code on a GitHub public repo and send us the link so that we can help you troubleshoot this.

Comment: Hello, well I am wondering maybe it was a mistake in adding the REPO. I followed this procedure, I cloned the REPO, assembledRelease, built APK, then I added it as a module to my android studio project, and added it as a compile dependency in my app. Is this the correct procedure?

Comment: Also do you guys have a company number...?

Comment: ya it looks like its not recognizing my import of org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFuture connect

Comment: For further assistance, please send us a GitHub repository link where we can browse your entire code to see if we find where the issue is coming from. To contact streamdata support, please send an email at support@streamdata.io